# Colorbox: pop-up image with link to external site on click

Tags: colorbox

I hope someone can help me. I have colorbox working on a new client site, but I'm having troubles figuring out how to add code that will allow for the image that pops up to be clicked and then linked to an external site in a new tab.

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a[rel='pop']").colorbox({transition:"fade", speed: 250});
```

});

```
<a href="../images/about.babyknitskit.png" rel="pop" title="<a href='http://www.chroniclebooks.com/site/catalog/index.php?main_page=pubs_product_book_info&products_id=6499&store=books'>Get it at Chronicle Books</a>"><span class="h2">Baby Knits Kit</span> (2007)<br>Chronicle Books<br></a>
```

In the above, when Baby Knits Kit is clicked a pop-up opens fine with the image I created (about.babyknitskit.png). On top of the pop-up there's "Get it at Chronicle Books" and when I click it will take me to that site (in the same tab which I don't want). Instead, I would like the about.babyknitskit.png image to be clickable and opening up the link in a new window.

Any thoughts much appreciated. I hope I've given you guys enough information as I'm new to all of this and stackoverflow.

Comment: And I have another question on the exact same as above. If I don't want to use an image for a pop-up in Colorbox but html text instead how do I write that and how do I then include a link to an external link (that opens in a new window) to text within that html? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the html property of colorbox. Alternatively you could use the href property with 'inline' set to true. I have defined a custom attribute for the anchor for easier extraction, alternatively you could write a regex pattern to extract it from the title attribute.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[rel='pop']").colorbox({transition:"fade", speed: 250, html: function(){
            var html = $('<a href="' + $(this).data('image-link') + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" /></a>');
            return html;
        }});
    });

<a href="_images/luke_header-bkg.jpg" rel="pop" title="<a href='http://www.chroniclebooks.com/site/catalog/index.php?main_page=pubs_product_book_info&products_id=6499&store=books'>Get it at Chronicle Books</a>" data-image-link="http://www.chroniclebooks.com/site/catalog/index.php?main_page=pubs_product_book_info&products_id=6499&store=books"><span class="h2">Baby Knits Kit</span> (2007)<br>Chronicle Books<br></a>
```